# How to add time instances to ontology

Tags: instance, ontology

I have created a time ontology in protege, in which I have to add minute, seconds and hour values as 09,19, etc. At output I want to show time as 11:30:00. When I added instances to hour and then seconds it showed me that individual already added. How to resolve that issue?

Comment: Hello @jonathon, please don't edit your question with extensive changes after you've gotten an answer. Ask another question instead. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/1288408

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve is to have  a single class, say `Time`, for which you can specify the hours, minutes and seconds. This is in fact an example of an [n-ary relation](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/), where you model the time relation as a class. A way to model this then is:

```
DataProperty: hours
    Domain: Time 
    Range: xsd:byte[>= "0"^^xsd:byte , <= "24"^^xsd:byte]


DataProperty: minutes>
    Domain: Time
    Range: xsd:byte[>= "0"^^xsd:byte , <= "60"^^xsd:byte]

DataProperty: seconds>
    Domain: Time
    Range: xsd:byte[>= "60"^^xsd:byte , <= "0"^^xsd:byte]

Class: Time
```

Then to specify, let say the opening time of some store, as 8:30, you can create the following individual:

```
Individual: openingTime
    Types: Time

    Facts:  
     hours  "8"^^xsd:byte,
     minutes  "30"^^xsd:byte,
     seconds  "0"^^xsd:byte
```